# Restore state of ViewPager

Tags: android

I have activity where I have loaded tabs with viewpager, my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
            .add(R.string.tab1, Rate.class)
            .add(R.string.tab2, Genres.class)
            .add(R.string.tab3, Search.class)
            .add(R.string.tab4, Player.class)
            .add(R.string.tab5, Genres.class)
            .create());

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
    viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);




}
```

I'm using library SmartTabLayout, I know if it's not clear for everyone but maybe somebody knows the way to restore activity state after Pause or open pager on specific tab(also important).

Comment: You can save position of current tab into sharedpreference in on pause and on destroy. And in oncreate check if values exists in sharedpreference, if value exists then set that value for position of tab .

Comment: save data to "new MyApplication", read them on resume;

Comment: We can probably give you a good answer if you let us know what exact information do you want to persist and when you want to persist it. Ex: Do you want to persist your information on rotation/configuration change or between app start-ups?

Comment: only start ups, it's forced portait